# is there anyway to retrieve " ^ " in POST method from web?

Tags: python, post, web, mod-wsgi

Is there anyway to retrieve ^ symbol in a POST method from the web?

Currently, I am using mod_wsgi and trying to retrieve the data to the python script.

Comment: You might clarify what symbol that really is. Is it ASCII "hat", or unicode combining character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely you can receive ^ in a POST.

```
POST /some/url HTTP/1.0
Host: somehost

^
```

It's probably not the most useful POST in the world, but nothing is stopping someone from POSTing it.

Comment: It was my mistake, actually ^ cannot be used on console